# InvalidOperationException: The MetadataAddress or Authority must use HTTPS unless disabled for development by setting RequireHttpsMetadata=false

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an **ASP.NET Core 2.2** application. I have recently started getting the above error when we deploy our app to our test server. This is an *IIS* server with a valid *HTTPS* certificate. We navigate to the app using the *HTTPS* authority. I can't understand why I am now getting this error. What could have changed to cause this error.

I know I can set `RequireHttpsMetadata = false` and this will fix the issue, but I would prefer to understand why this is happening. What would have caused it to suddenly start happening.

Everything works fine in Development.

Comment: I have the same issue - I also don't understand what URL / connection in particular is causing this error.

Comment: The MetadataAddress property is set in the Owin configuration files; for Sitecore this is in the Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config file, but depending on your solution and flavor of OWIN implementation it could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

In your Sitecore website, ensure that the identityServerAuthority variable's value starts with https.
In **\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config**

```
<sc.variable name="identityServerAuthority" value="https://identity.my-domainexmaple.com" />
```

No protocol means that http will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after installing new fresh XP1 instance, and I found the problem is coming from Owin configuration.

Once disabled the Owin authentication by enabling this config file **"\App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler.config.example**" everything worked as expected!

This has to be done on CM & CD, unless you have the correct configurations for Owin Authentication.